# pulling data and parse from api ionic angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this api, have function for getting data from api.
Page has pageelements, inside page elementa are data, in data field saved title, text, image.
How get data from field data?

```
getMenu() {
return this.http.get('http://site.dev/api/menu/7');}

{
"id": 26,
"name": "Default",
"title": "default",
"pageelements": [
  {
    "id": 15,
    "page_id": 26,
    "element_type_id": 3,
    "data": "{\"image\":\"download.jpg\"}",
    "created_at": "2018-04-20 10:08:24",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-20 10:12:05",
    "position": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "page_id": 26,
    "element_type_id": 1,
    "data": "{\"title\":\"Naslov neki\"}",
    "created_at": "2018-04-20 10:10:11",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-20 10:12:05",
    "position": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "page_id": 26,
    "element_type_id": 1,
    "data": "{\"title\":\"Naslov 2\"}",
    "created_at": "2018-04-20 10:11:06",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-20 10:11:27",
    "position": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "page_id": 26,
    "element_type_id": 3,
    "data": "{\"image\":\"download (1).jpg\"}",
    "created_at": "2018-04-20 10:11:36",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-20 10:11:52",
    "position": 4
  }
],
```

},

Comment: Your question and code is not clear.. Please specify preciously what your problem is

Comment: Try this `let img = JSON.parse(res[0].pageelements[0].data).image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your api data is in page object. Then user this code to access data.

```
let pageelements = this.page.pageelements;
        for(let i=0; i<pageelements.length;i++) {
            console.log(pageelements[i].data);

            console.log(JSON.parse(pageelements[i].data).image);
            console.log(JSON.parse(pageelements[i].data).title);
        }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yn8tb5